# React Native giving Error while installing app

Tags: firebase, react-native

After installing react-native-googlesignin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin) package this error occurs

```
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/Users/rohanvirangna/Desktop/React Native Projects/NotesApp/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:27: error: a type with the same simple name is already defined by the single-type-import of RNGoogleSigninPackage
import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;
^
Note: /Users/rohanvirangna/Desktop/React Native Projects/NotesApp/android/app/src/debug/java/com/igniteapp/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```